# Which SPField property specifies if one is checked during view creation?

Tags: view, 2016, spfield, default-value

When I create a Standard View via the browser, some of the Columns are checked to be **Display**-ed by default, and some are not(see bottom of image).

I am trying to build a view server side, and [have access to the individual fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_properties.aspx).  But I can't tell what property provides this information from the documentation and from googling.

Does anyone know if one can gain access to this **DisplayCheckedByDefaultWhenBuildingStandardView** flag programmatically? (Ill take either server side or client side)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Standard View** and **Start from: All items**, both do the same: you get a copy of the Deafult View

[image]

If you create a new View with code you have to set the ViewFields property

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=create+view+viewfields

So there is **not** a property on the individual Fields that indicates it is used in a View